# How to check IF user has ALREADY liked the facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect

I used the facebook after liked redirection code like this . but I cant find a solution for user already liked. if user already liked redirect page.

the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true
            });
            FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 400, height: 80 });

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                function(response) 
            {
                    alert('Thank You');
                    // put redirect code here eg
                    window.location = "http://www.example.com/FacebookAutoRedirect.asp"; 
            }
            );

           **if also liked 
            {
             window.location = "http://www.example.com/FacebookAutoRedirect.asp";
            }**

        };

        //Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                  '//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>
```

best regards

Answer (score 1):

That´s only possible if you authorize the user (you need a Facebook app for that), with the "user_likes" permission > After that you can read his likes and check if he liked a specific page.

Facebook docs about user login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Careful with that, you cannot just open it without any user interaction:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

Or with the PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Comment: Yes I know that but when I try to do the script open a popup but all browsers blocked the popup ! Do you know any different way ?

Comment: you have to open that popup on mouse click, you cannot just open it whenever you want to. you can also redirect to the login url, see php sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ (added that to the answer)

Comment: The Like Popup is opened from code inside an iframe pointed at Facebook's servers, so it's events are invisible to JavaScript running on your domain.

Comment: jason, i have no clue what you are trying to say and to whom your comment is directed...lol (no offense, if that sounds like one. i really have no clue)